# Compare compiled .NET assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, debugging, reverse-engineering

Are there any good programs out there to compare to compile .NET assemblies?

For example I have HelloWorld.dll (1.0.0.0) and HelloWorld.dll (2.0.0.0), and I want to compare differences how can I do this?

I know I can use .NET Reflector and use the Assembly Diff plugin.  Are there any other good tools out there to do this?

Comment: Just sheer binary differences? Or public interface differences?

Comment: If you can use .NET Reflector with Assembly Diff, why do you need another tool?  Is the plugin insufficient for your needs?  If so, how?

Comment: @strager: in my experience, it doesn't work

Comment: @strager: It does not let me compare two builds of the same assembly, at least when their version is the same.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Ways to Compare .NET Assemblies](http://immitev.blogspot.com/2008/10/ways-to-compare-net-assemblies.html) suggests

Commercial:

- [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)

Free:

- [JustAssembly](http://www.telerik.com/justassembly) (only shows differences in API)
- [BitDiffer](https://github.com/grennis/bitdiffer) (same)
- [Reflector Diff Add-in](http://www.codingsanity.com/diff.htm) (which you've already discovered, but not available anymore)

---

Existing compare tools like Beyond Compare (commercial) can do this by special configuration. Here's how to do this for Beyond Compare:

- Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Options</kbd>
- Click <kbd>New..</kbd>, select "Text format", click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Give it a name (say, EXE, or DLL), and specify the mask as `*.exe` or `*.dll`
- Click on tab <kbd>Conversion</kbd> and select "External program (Unicode filenames)"
- Under "Loading", specify the path to `ildasm` and add  `%s /OUT:%t /NOBAR` (i.e.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ildasm.exe %s /OUT:%t /NOBAR`)
- Make sure to check <kbd>disable editing</kbd>.
- Click <kbd>Save</kbd>, then <kbd>Close</kbd>
- Restart BC and open two `exe` files to compare, it should decompile into `ilasm` automatically now.

You can also add syntax highlighting to this new format. I plan to send the syntax file to them so that it'll [become available to share](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv3).

Comment: Just a note that Framework Design Studio is pretty useless. More like a book pusher that teaches the style and then eventually we all realise those guidelines are not the answer to anything. Reflector addin is about the only one that is free and good but under-developed.

Comment: I've spent 20 minutes today trying to use the reflector add in and I don't think that it works. I tried comparing 2 assemblies that were named the same thing in 2 different directories.

Comment: Telerik's JustDecompile lets you do this, but it's somewhat manual -- you use the "create project" method to generate source files for each (into different directories, obviously) then use something like Beyond Compare or DiffMerge etc to compare the source code.

Comment: @jcollum It appears that you can compare two assemblies, but they can't be "the same", as in using the same namespace and such... which makes this completely pointless

Comment: See more explanations about NDepend diff here  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-diff-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 27):

Two ways.

You could ILDASM and diff with classic tools.

Or you could use NDepends, which will cost for that feature.

[Piece to C# bloaters..]

Comment: +1, just ildasm both files, then diff the text output; you don't need expensive toos

Comment: I love easy solutions like this.

Answer (score 12):

I just had to compare two revisions of the same DLL, which had the same version (I needed to implement a small hotfix, and deploy the DLL in production, but I wanted to make sure that no other changes leaked into code). Ideally, I would want the Assemby Diff add-in to show me the difference, but it does not work (it thinks that I'm comparing a DLL to itself). So this is what I did:

- Created two folders to hold disassembled source files.
- Used the **Reflector**'s **Export** option (from context menu) to generate source files from each DLL in the folders created in previous step.
- Used the free [**DiffMerge**](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) tool to compare two directories; the tools showed me the modified files and the difference.

It's a bit kludgy, but seems to work. I wish the Assembly Diff add-in worked, though.

UPDATE: The latest version of the Assembly Diff add-in is supposed to fix the issue of comparing two versions of the same assembly. Give it a try.

Comment: WindDiff that comes with Visual Studio is effective too.

Comment: I assume you meant the WinDiff (one 'd') utility. It's OK, but DiffMerge is so much nicer.

Answer (score 7):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) offers many features to compare compiled .NET assemblies.

First from the NDepend Start Page click: **Compare 2 versions of a code base**. This will let you provide older and newer versions of your assemblies.

[image: NDepend Compare 2 Versions of a code base]

Then after NDepend has analyzed both older and newer assemblies, you can use the panel **Search by Change**. It is dedicated to browse assemblies code diff. Notice that:

- If source code is available, just right click an element and click **Diff Source**. In the NDepend options you can plug to NDepend any code diff tool (Visual Studio, Beyond Compare...)
- If you don't have the source code and just only the raw assemblies, there is the option **Compare older and newer version disassembled with ILSpy**. [ILSpy v7.0 and upper versions are supported](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). This menu works on assembly, namespace, type and method level and you can choose to decompile to C# or IL.

[image: Compare .NET Assemblies with NDepend]

Notice also in the screenshot that a [CQLinq code query](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) is generated to browse the diff.

```
from m in Application.Methods 
where m.CodeWasChanged() 
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

Many others default diff queries and rules are proposed by default, that will let you browse .NET code diff in a smart way.

- [Types that used to be 100% covered but not anymore](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_that_used_to_be_100__covered_but_not_anymore.html)
- [API Breaking Changes: Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_API_Breaking_Changes__Methods.html)
- [Avoid making complex methods even more complex](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_making_complex_methods_even_more_complex_%28Source_CC%29.html)
- [Avoid decreasing code coverage by tests of types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_decreasing_code_coverage_by_tests_of_types.html)
- [From now, all types added or refactored should respect basic quality principles](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_From_now,_all_types_added_or_refactored_should_respect_basic_quality_principles.html)
- [Avoid transforming an immutable type into a mutable one](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_transforming_an_immutable_type_into_a_mutable_one.html)
- [Heuristic to find types moved from one namespace or assembly to another](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Heuristic_to_find_types_moved_from_one_namespace_or_assembly_to_another.html)

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of the tool*.

Comment: To those open source devs and people with shallow wallets, you do need to buy the professional edition for this feature, it's not in the trial.

Comment: To those open source devs, we are always glad to sponsor a public OSS project with a free license, just contact us. Also the trial model has evolved and you can download now a 14-day fully functional trial (including diff features)

Comment: @ChrisS Nowadays the NDepend trial is full-featured and what is explained is supported by trial

Answer (score 2):

One more option is [LibCheck](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11287) from Microsoft.

Pretty old console tool for just getting public API diff. I could not run without debugging and retargeting to a more recent .net version. However, it gave me very clear output and I am going to use it later.

Here is an [article](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-developer-power/0596527543/ch04s05.html) with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thinking outside the box approach whcih works fine.

1. Dump your old and new assemblies with dnSpy, dotPeek or JustDecompile into projects.
2. Create a new Git repo and commit the old assembly code first.
3. In your local repo folder delete all the files/folders except for ".git" and paste the new assembly files.
4. Either commit the new changes and view changes on say Github or use  a Git viewer like Fork. Easy code comparison for free.

Comment: I found dumping with DnSpy into separate projects and then selecting the separate folders with WinMerge did exactly what I was looking for, while requiring more than one tool.  Basically same as what you say

Answer (score -11):

Java has a nice one: [Semantic Diff Utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523307/semantic-diff-utilities/)

Comment: Interesting, but not relevant