# How to automatically detect assembly interface change?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Assembly A was released in version 1.0
Some patches are developed on A.

These patches could involve either 100% internal code (ex: changing implementation of private function) or they could affect A interface even in a way that does not break compilation of depending assemblies (ex: public constant value changed).

How  to automatically detect that assembly A interface has changed so that you know you might need to deliver A-dependent assemblies as well?

Comment: You should check out NDepend. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1280252/201088).

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution is (if you're detecting them at runtime) is provide some kind of manifest for assembly where you define *version* and *dependent assemblies list* (that can vary based on the version).

Comment: I already have that list. But if changes are only internal, I do not want to deliver depending assemblies. So I need something more.

Comment: @sthiers: if changes are *only* internal, change only version number and leave dependent assemblies list (if any) invariant.

Comment: yes, problem is to automatically detect whether changes are internal or not.

Comment: @sthiers: just check if the *version* is a different. You have version informaiton in the assembly too. Recover it with reflection.