# Code Changes in .NET Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Each time a .NET library is build a new assembly with public key token, date, etc is generated.
Is there a standard way to find out if this new assembly contains code changes?

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you release a new assembly with code changes you should be updating its version number and not just its build number - so if you're doing things by the book you should be able to compare assembly version numbers (ignoring the build number part).

Comment: What the heck are you talking about? If you want an answer, you need to describe a concrete scenario!

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to diff the dll by its source code...

Comment: @Matthew Watson Suppose I forget to update this assembly version?

Comment: probably not; you can't tell if there is code change unless you have access to the source version control server so you can compare the revisions between the 2 builds. But it's still error prone.

Comment: @Aron yes, I want to diff dlls by source code

Comment: No I don't know of a good way to do this. I would recommend you use the MsBuild Community Build Tasks to tag your assemblies with your revision history.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Assembly Diff / Compare Tool - What's available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280252/net-assembly-diff-compare-tool-whats-available)

Comment: he can disassemble using this [CLICK](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77/is-there-any-way-to-decompile-a-net-assembly-or-program) and later diff. But dont know its its the best way