# Automatically create/check minor/major version for .NET solution

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio

We use the following scheme for versions:

```
major.minor.build
```

where

- each breaking change increments major (resets minor)
- each new feature increments minor
- each commit increases build

Is there a way/tool to automatically check if there is

- no breaking change (e.g. changing interface) when there's only a change in minor
- no new features (e.g. no new interfaces) when there's only a change in build
  ?

A tool that automatically creates major/minor would also be ok.

Comment: You'd need an AI to detect whether there are new features or not.

Comment: I would say no. Even an unchanged interface signature can have a changed implementation that changes behaviour. A valid call in the previous version now throws an execption. No interface change but still a breaking change. If you have a contracts based application that might be a good indicator if they change but that would still be far from perfect.

Comment: Rethinking it. Unittests are what you are asking for ;)

Comment: I found another question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/652459/1254743) and the solution (NDepend) looks promising. Especially since I can define the rules. Checking itself may be only on the CI, but that's fine.