# Limit Git Diff to one or more functions?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

I set `*.py diff=python` in `.git/info/attributes`. So Git knows where function boundaries. git diff -W can even make sure the whole function is shown.

But is there a way to limit the output of a git diff to just a particular function (or more than one)?

(Failing that, I guess it's awk...)

EDIT This would also be useful for `git log` and `git rev-list`: don't show me every commit that modifies views.py, show me commits that modify a certain function in it. (Yes, in an ideal world, views.py wouldn't be a 2000 line behemoth frequently modified by 8 different developers...)

Comment: You might find this worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523307/semantic-diff-utilities

Comment: Yeah that's interesting, but it looks like a pretty immature field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513783/263268), we have a solution.

Use the awk script in that answer, combined with a bit of bash:

`~/scripts/grit:`

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
shift 1
if [ "$cmd" = "" ]; then
  git
# other commands not relevant to this question go here
elif [ $cmd = "funcdiff" ]; then
  git show "$1:$3" | awk -f ~/scripts/getfunc.awk -v f=$4 > /tmp/.tmp1
  git show "$2:$3" | awk -f ~/scripts/getfunc.awk -v f=$4 > /tmp/.tmp2
  git diff -W --no-index /tmp/.tmp1 /tmp/.tmp2 

else
  git $cmd $@
fi
```

Example usage: `grit funcdiff 009e75 8b7a14 ./staging.py write_uploaded`

This could also be added as a git alias in ~/.gitconfig

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any other option (other than the `--function-context` or its `-W` short option, already mentioned) able to restrict a diff output to a single function.

And even that `-W` option isn't always enough, knowing that a 'function' can vary greatly from language to language, as illustrated in this [blog post](http://johnkary.net/git-1-7-8-changes-for-the-everyday-developer/):

> I’ve found this option rather unreliable, at least within a large PHP class.
>   My tests found `--function-context` often results in displaying almost all of the original file, and git appears ignorant of PHP’s function boundaries.
>   The number of context lines before and after a change seem random, and the diff doesn’t necessarily always show all lines of the function, either.
>
> The [original patch message](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/183199) that introduced this change sheds some light:
>
> > This implementation has the same shortcoming as the one in grep, namely that there is no way to explicitly find the end of a function.
> >     That means that a few lines of extra context are shown, right up to the next recognized function begins.
>
> So it appears detecting a function’s boundaries is difficult for git.
>   It seems in this instance, git never detects a function boundary and gives us the context of the entire file.

---

As the [OP Steve Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263268/steve-bennett) points out, a potential solution would be to define a git alias which would extract the function in the revision before and after modification, in order to diff on those 2 'temp' files.
Example in "[Creating Git Aliases](http://davidwalsh.name/git-aliases)" and "[Bash script to select a single Python function from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512351/bash-script-to-select-a-single-python-function-from-a-file)".

This is an ad-hoc solution which will be able to parse the specific type of source the OP happens to work with in his repo.

Comment: Yeah, I'm now trying another tack, using git alias with a script to parse the file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512351/bash-script-to-select-a-single-python-function-from-a-file

I was inspired by this post, which I ran into completely randomly: http://davidwalsh.name/git-aliases

Comment: @SteveBennett Interesting approach. I have included it in the answer for more visibility, and to contrast this ad-hoc solution with the lack of a more "generic" feature.